# Looking for approach to minify kafkajs as a JS library instead of NPM

Tags: kafkajs

I am looking for minified/dist version in order to include directly in our packaged product as a library due to limitations with npm on a SaaS platform. Has someone used/created a dist version of Kafkajs code?

Not able to find a minified version of JS.

Comment: People use tools like webpack for this.